# Does the following hold?

Tags: matrices, inequality, trace

I have that $A$ is a matrix that has real eigenvalues, which are non-positive, but it is not a symmetric matrix. Also, $B$ is a positive semi-definite matrix that is diagonal. Does the following hold:

$$\text{Tr}\,(AB) \leq 0$$

Comment: @ user2457324 , it's your business to randomly choose two matrices $A,B$ as above and to test $tr(AB)$. Moreover, you are unable to see what is the correct answer from the two below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For example take

$ A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-ab & -b  \\
a & 1  \end{array} \right) $

$ B = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 1+ab  \end{array} \right) $

$A$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $1 - ab$, which are non-positive if $a, b$ are large. $B$ is positive definite if $a, b > 0 .$ 
We have: $ Tr(AB) = 1 > 0 .$

Comment: @loupblanc, VictorZurkowski can you all please take a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887712/find-2-norm-conditions-on-a-matrix-to-make-the-following-true
I would really appreciate it. thanks.